# How to call a function automatically when some condition gets false?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, evm

I am having a bidding session where every time a person Bids on some product it checks the condition if the bidding session is valid or not,

I want to trigger a finalize bid function which will finalize the bid and will proceed with other formalities?

Is it possible? As of my thinking, for executing a function in the EVM, gas is needed, provided by some of the account holders only, either an EOA or a Contract Account.

Feel free to share an approach for doing this.

Thank You .

Comment: Generally, you need someone to call a function. In an auction, the person to make that function call is usually either the winner of the auction or the seller. (They're the ones who have something to gain by calling such a function.)

Comment: @smarx , how to call the approve from an eoa ? 
Can I do it like `tokenInstance.approve(address(this), _bidValue)` 
Will it approve the contract to transfer tokens from the msg.sender to itself , Using `transferFrom ` ?

Comment: I'm not sure how that question connects with your original question. But yes, if account `X` calls `approve(Y, n)`, then `Y` can transfer up to `n` of `X`'s tokens via `transferFrom(X, Z, n)`.